# Problemas para ejecutar Web Service tasks en SSIS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, webservice, api, ssis

Tengo un proyecto que consume un servicio web. Como parametro mandatorio me pide un ApiKey y eso lo ejecuto a partir de un Script Tasks en SSIS.

La ejecucion se hace sin problemas. Cuando vengo a llamar uno de los serivios web, tengo creado un Web Service tasks, donde no me pide ningun parametro de entrada.

Le tengo creado en el output type un File Connection que va hacia un archivo .xml

El problema que cada vez que ejecuto el servicio me da por error (Could not execute the Web method. The error is: Index was outside the bounds of the array)

He tratado de ver en internet pero no encuentro nada, alguien podria guiarme?

Comment: por el error, "Could not execute the Web method. The error is: Index was outside the bounds of the array", sería obvio un error dentro de la operación que realiza el método, pero que version SSIS usas?

Comment: Hola uso la version 2012

Comment: Podrías agregar algo de código de tu método?

Comment: Esto puede ocurrir cuando el web service devuelve un array vacío.

Comment: Para mi es correcto lo del tema del ARRAY. Pero solo que me ocurre cuando envio el array como parametro. no reonocce el typo, no interpreta el array y lo ve como una variable vacia. intente modificar el DTSX desde XML, modificando la propiedad del objeto variable de primitive a variable. Como lo hace en los casos de una sola. NO FUNCIONO.
Intente con un parche ... no funciono. Intente actualizando el datatools ... nada todo sigue igual.